# Grep only second part after space

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I have a parser in a shell script:

Here is the input file to parse from (input.txt):

```
input.txt:
system.switch_cpus.commit.swp_count                 0                       # Number of s/w prefetches committed
  system.switch_cpus.commit.refs                2682887                       # Number of memory references committed
  system.switch_cpus.commit.loads               1779328                       # Number of loads committed                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  system.switch_cpus.commit.membars                   0                       # Number of memory barriers committed
  system.switch_cpus.commit.branches             921830                       # Number of branches committed
  system.switch_cpus.commit.vec_insts                 0                       # Number of committed Vector instructions.
  system.switch_cpus.commit.fp_insts                  0                       # Number of committed floating point instructions.
  system.switch_cpus.commit.int_insts          10000000                       # Number of committed integer instructions.
```

The script does the following:

```
 $ cpu1_name="system.switch_cpus"
 $ echo "$(grep "${cpu1_name}.commit.loads" ./input.txt |grep -Eo '[0-9]+')"
 correct expected output: 1779328
```

But on another file the variable "cpu1_name" is changed to "system.switch_cpus**_1**"
Running the same script now gives me 2 values:

```
New input file:
system.switch_cpus_1.commit.swp_count               0                       # Number of s/w prefetches committed
 system.switch_cpus_1.commit.refs              2682887                       # Number of memory references committed
 system.switch_cpus_1.commit.loads             1779328                       # Number of loads committed                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 system.switch_cpus_1.commit.membars                 0                       # Number of memory barriers committed
 system.switch_cpus_1.commit.branches           921830                       # Number of branches committed
 system.switch_cpus_1.commit.vec_insts               0                       # Number of committed Vector instructions.
 system.switch_cpus_1.commit.fp_insts                0                       # Number of committed floating point instructions.   


Modified Script line:
$ cpu1_name="system.switch_cpus_1"
$ echo "$(grep "${cpu1_name}.commit.loads" ./new_input.txt |grep -Eo '[0-9]+')"
1
1779328
```

As you can see, the piped grep is searching for any number and reporting an extra "1" due to the changed variable name.

Is there a way to only select the second part of the number (i.e. only 1779328)?
I know I can use `awk'{print $2}` but that would mean changing a lot of lines in the script. So I was thinking if there was a easier trick with the existing script lines.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `_` is considered a word char, there is no word boundary between the `_` and `1`. There are word boundaries on both sides of the expected numbers.

Thus, all you need to do is to use your pattern with word boundaries. You may use `w` option to match as a whole word, or choose between `\b` or `\<` / `\>`, whichever your `grep` supports:

```
grep -Ewo '[0-9]+'
grep -Eo '\b[0-9]+\b'
grep -Eo '\<[0-9]+\>'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/2R75dH).

Note you may also use `sed` to extract the second non-whitespace chunk from the lines:

```
sed -E 's/^\s*\S+\s+(\S+).*/\1/'
```

See this demo.

**Details**

- `^` - start of line
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\S+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\S+)` - 1+ non-whitespace chars (Group 1, just what we keep with `\1` placeholder in the replacement pattern)
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Answer (score 1):

The values (numbers you are trying to get) are obviously surrounded by spaces. So you can use possitive-lookbehind `(?<=pattern)` and possitive-lookahead `(?=pattern)` regex conditionals to find those matches that have a space around them.

Note that to use these conditionals you need to use `-P` flag in grep.

Comment: @MadPhysicist They do with `-P` flag.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: yes they do if you put in perl regex mode with `-P` flag just check my answer

Comment: Neat. Learned a new thing today. +1

Answer (score 1):

Awk can do it all in one step (no pipeline needed):

```
awk -v x="${cpu1_name}.commit.loads" '$1==x{print $2}' input.txt
```

This should be portable and work with any POSIX awk.

#### Example

```
$ awk -v x="${cpu1_name}.commit.loads" '$1==x{print $2}' input.txt
1779328
$ awk -v x="${cpu1_name}.commit.loads" '$1==x{print $2}' new_input.txt
1779328
```

#### How it works

- `-v x="${cpu1_name}.commit.loads"`

  This defines an awk variable `x` that contains the name that we are looking for.
- `$1==x{print $2}`

  If the first field, `$1`, is equal to `x`, then print the second field, `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your grep command in :

```
grep -oP '(?<=\s)[0-9]+'
```

To impose the presence of a space before your digit chains, even better try:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\s)\d+'
```

or eventually in `grep -oP '(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s)'` or in `grep -oP '(?<=\s)[0-9]+(?=\s)'`